# Apache pass and login authentication partially failed

Tags: apache, authentication, apache2

I try to add an Apache login and pass authentication.
It works ... well, not as intended.

I have 2 server names, one ssh and a "normal" one.

This is how I've done it so far :

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride AuthConfig
order deny,allow
allow from XX.X.X.XXX 127.0.0.1
deny from all
AuthName "Login/Pass"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/user.acl
AuthGroupFile /path/groups.acl
require group adminGroup
Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

I have 2 VirtualHost defined as follow (one SSH and the other one "normal") :

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot //IP/path/XXXX
  ServerName dev.admin.com:8080
  RewriteEngine on
 <IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
  WebLogicHost 127.0.0.1
  WebLogicPort 7509
  WLCookieName   CookieName
 </IfModule>
  <Location /weblogic>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    ErrorPage /page-non-trouvee
    pathTrim /weblogic
  </Location>
  <Location /dynamic>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    ErrorPage /page-non-trouvee
    pathTrim /dynamic
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to go to dev.admin.com:8080 it works fine, Apache asks for login and pass and recognized them.
But when I try to go to dev.admin.com:8080/weblogic/XXX it asks for a login and pass but don't recognize the ones declared.

I tried to use the `<location />` and `<location>` tags in the 2 VirtualHosts ... same result.

I seems that it is because of the use of the weblogic-handler. For example, dev.admin.com:8080/weblogic works, dev.admin.com:8080/weblogic/XXX doesn't.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem. In fact, my Apache conf. relies on a weblogic-apache plugin which alter the authentification process in Apache by redirecting to the Weblogic server before that the authentification is validated.

Comment: @Sebas I am really sorry but I don't remember at all